# sum of the previous two elements of the list

Tags: python, loops

I want to use for loop to test whether each member of list has the sum of the previous two elements of the list. The output should something like this.
Thanks in advance

```
list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,85,143]
```

input :`[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,85,143]`

output:

```
0+1=1
True
1+1=2 
True
1+2=3
True
2+3=5
True
3+8=11
True
8+13=21
True
13+21=34
True
21+34=55
True
34+55=89
False
55+85 =140
False
```

I tired some loop logic but not able to get the desired result e.g

```
l =[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,85,143] 
sum=0 
for element in l:
    print(element)
    sum +=element 
    print(sum)
```

Comment: Why is `3+8=11` false?

Comment: Where is `85` in the input?

Comment: Are you trying to verify a Fibonacci Sequence? Or just in general meaning?

Comment: i think you used if condition. if ( list.length - 2 == index) then continue loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,88,143]
prev_prev_item = 0
for idx in range(1, len(my_list)):
    print(idx, my_list[idx], my_list[idx] == my_list[idx-1] + prev_prev_item)
    prev_prev_item = my_list[idx-1]
```

output -

```
1 1 True
2 2 True
3 3 True
4 5 True
5 8 True
6 13 True
7 21 True
8 34 True
9 55 True
10 88 False
11 143 True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the list together with itself and iterate over that. For the first list in the zip prepend with `[0]`. Avoiding the indices should help the readability:

```
l = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,88,143] 

for a, b, c in zip([0]+l, l, l[1:]):
    print(f"{a} + {b} = {c} {a + b == c}")
```

Prints:

```
0 + 1 = 1 True
1 + 1 = 2 True
1 + 2 = 3 True
2 + 3 = 5 True
3 + 5 = 8 True
5 + 8 = 13 True
8 + 13 = 21 True
13 + 21 = 34 True
21 + 34 = 55 True
34 + 55 = 88 False
55 + 88 = 143 True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,88,143]
for i in range(len(list)-2):
    if (list[i+2] == (list[i]+list[i+1])):
        print(list[i],'+',list[i+1],'=',list[i+2],'True')
    else: 
        print(list[i],'+',list[i+1],'=',list[i+2],'False')
```

Simply go through the list (for loop) and compare the sum of the ith and i+1th item with the i+2th item (if statement). It should be easy to follow.
The output should be the same as yours:

```
1 + 1 = 2 True
1 + 2 = 3 True
2 + 3 = 5 True
3 + 5 = 8 True
5 + 8 = 13 True
8 + 13 = 21 True
13 + 21 = 34 True
21 + 34 = 55 True
34 + 55 = 88 False
55 + 88 = 143 True
```